# Running /bin/ps with NSTask with App Sandboxing enabled

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox, nstask, appstore-sandbox

I have a cocoa app that needs to get a list of processes. After enabling app sandboxing, I get `/bin/ps: Operation not permitted`. Is there another way of doing this that's compatible with app sandboxing? I am running this via `NSTask`

Comment: That's why sandboxing is one of the most stupidest ideas on desktop computers since the late 40's.

Comment: Which attributes of the processes are you interested in?

Comment: @mahaltertin the path

Answer (score 1):

You can't run `ps` from the sandbox, because it is a set-uid root program.

There is no other documented way to get a process list. There is, however, an undocumented API described in `libproc.h`. I'm not sure if you can use it from the sandbox, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications] to get a list of all processes. This will return an array of NSRunningApplications.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsworkspace
https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsworkspace/1534059-runningapplications
https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsrunningapplication

Comment: that does not return a list of all processes. just a list of user processes.